# Counting pending bookings using a subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can this query be improved? Is there a way to eliminate the duplicate function call?

```
-- a Special Group has many Items which have many Bookings
create function f_BookingsForSpecialGroup(@specialGroupId varchar(99))
returns table as
    return select * from v_Booking where ITEM_CODE in
        (select ITEM_CODE from v_Item i where i.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID = @specialGroupId);
go


create view v_SpecialGroup as
select (NON_BAD_BOOKINGS - PAID_BOOKINGS) as PENDING_BOOKINGS, * from
(
select
    (select count(*) from f_BookingsForSpecialGroup(g.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID) where IS_BAD=0) as NON_BAD_BOOKINGS,
    (select count(*) from f_BookingsForSpecialGroup(g.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID) where IS_PAID=1) as PAID_BOOKINGS,
    *
from SPECIAL_GROUP g
) g
go
```

The view v_SpecialGroup is never queried directly by the application; it is used to build other views which select individual columns as needed. (You can think of v_SpecialGroup as a "base view" which exists solely to augment the SPECIAL_GROUP table. I have profiled this strategy and it seems that if you don't select the more expensive columns you don't pay for them, but I could be wrong of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the view returns all of the columns from a `SPECIAL_GROUP` table, along with an additional column counting bookings that are neither `is_bad` nor `is_paid`.

If so, you could use a common table expression* to simplify the logic a bit:

```
create view v_SpecialGroup as

with bookings_by_group as (
    select  i.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID,
            count(case when is_bad = 0 then 1 end) as NON_BAD_BOOKINGS,
            count(case when is_paid = 1 then 1 end) as PAID_BOOKINGS
    from    v_booking b join v_item i on b.ITEM_CODE = i.ITEM_CODE
    group by i.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID)
select  NON_BAD_BOOKINGS - PAID_BOOKINGS as PENDING_BOOKINGS,
        g.*
from    bookings_by_group b join SPECIAL_GROUP g on b.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID = g.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID
```

ps. It might also be possible to condense the logic further:

`count(case when is_bad = 0 and is_paid != 1 then 1 end) as PENDING_BOOKINGS`

it would depend on whether you had any bookings that were both `is_bad` and `is_paid`

*SQL Server must be >= 2008R2

Comment: This looks good. I came up with something similar using a cross join instead of a CTE. I will have to research the significance of using one vs the other.

Comment: You could compare the execution plans, you may well find that the optimiser executes both syntaxes in exactly the same way.

Comment: It turns out the CTE actually performed better whether or not I used the table-valued function. Very nice!

Comment: CTEs were introduced in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to eliminate the repeated function call, but as to whether or not it would improve performance you need to benchmark it. This method writes the resulting data into a temporary table, which means it will call the function only once when populating it, but in turn will mean that it will have to write the table to `tempdb` for that session. Here is how it could be written that way:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#SpecialBookings') is not null
    drop table tempdb..#SpecialBookings;

select *
into #SpecialBookings
from SPECIAL_GROUP as grp
    cross apply f_BookingsForSpecialGroup(grp.SPECIAL_GROUP_ID) as bookings
where (bookings.IS_BAD = 0 or bookings.IS_PAID = 1);

select (grpCounted.NON_BAD_BOOKINGS - grpCounted.PAID_BOOKINGS) as PENDING_BOOKINGS, * 
from 
(
    select
        (select count(*) from #SpecialBookings where IS_BAD=0) as NON_BAD_BOOKINGS,
        (select count(*) from #SpecialBookings where IS_PAID=1) as PAID_BOOKINGS,
        *
    from #SpecialBookings
) as grpCounted;

if object_id('tempdb..#SpecialBookings') is not null
    drop table tempdb..#SpecialBookings;
```

---

### `select *`

Do you really need ***all*** the fields from both the `SPECIAL_GROUP` table and the `f_BookingsForSpecialGroup`? If you do really need them, then fair enough, but otherwise, you [should not use `select *`](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

---

#### Aliases

As you can see I renamed your table aliases a bit to make your code easier to read. Whenever possible, avoid single-letter or otherwise meaningless aliases as they make the code less clear.

Comment: Thanks, I think a cross apply is exactly what I need. And I think I can get by without a temp table...

Comment: OK good, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to have a function that returns a table composed of two `INT`s, corresponding to each of your `COUNT`s:

```
BadCount INT, PaidCount INT
```

This function will compute both COUNTs based on a SPECIAL_GROUP_ID, so it should like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetContactInformation(@SPECIAL_GROUP_ID INT)
RETURNS @CountInfo TABLE 
(

    ContactID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    FirstName nvarchar(50) NULL, 
)
-- function body comes here
```

However, keep in mind that your function will be called for each row returned from `SPECIAL_GROUP` (clearly visible in profiler, estimated/actual plan does not show function calls, if I remember correctly), so performance might be affected.

Also, * should be avoided since it can lead to performance problems (selecting all columns may inhibit indexes usage) and also may also lead to unexpected results (changing table structure without procedure recompilation, means that * does not actually brings you all the columns).

If possible, please provide code from `f_BookingsForSpecialGroup` - maybe it can be rewritten to be more [set based](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/programming-sql-set-based-way).

Comment: Good point, I have updated the question to show `f_BookingsForSpecialGroup`